# Log all data passing on socket

Tags: python, python-sockets, audit-trail

How am I able to log all of the data passing on a Python socket?

For audit, security and debugging purposes I've attempted creating a few wrappers around the socket object. They log all of the data passed to methods like `.recv()` and `.sendall()`.

Unfortunately, there are a few main problems with that approach:

1. It is not forward / backwards compatible. A new method on the socket object for sending data in any Python minor version will not be logged. I can only allow using my custom object, but that will enforce my interface, without the possibility to create `__getattr__`.
2. In case of network disconnection in the middle of a `.sendall()`, I do not know what was already sent.

Python's built-in audit does not contain anything for the actual data passed on the socket.

I wish to avoid the usage of tcpdump and stay within the confines of Python.